# Получение значение цены на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Есть простенький сайт который мне нужно спарсить, но я столкнулся с проблемой парсинга цены на сайте, потому что она задана .jpg файлом, как ее можно было бы достать с помощью селениума?

```html
<td class="brief-price">
                <table>
                    <tbody><tr>
                        <td>
                            <img src="https://130.com.ua/published/SC/html/scripts/price.php?prc=ODhRbnxRKndjSWE1MjA5NjZ7UnZpI3d5P3I%2FIzFAMTI1QGdycEB1a0AwQDI%3D" alt="Ціна" title="Ціна">                     </td>
                    </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                <td style="font-size:0.98em;">
                                                            <b>у наявності</b>
                                                        </td>
                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                <td>
                                <div class="prdbrief_add2cart">
                <button type="submit" class="orange normal-btn" value="Купити" src="/published/publicdata/AUTO/attachments/SC/images/add2cart_small_uk.gif" title="Купити">Купити</button>
                </div>
                                </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td>
                                                <div class="sm-current-rating1"><div class="sm-current-rating1-back">&nbsp;</div><div class="sm-current-rating1-front" style="width: 39px;">&nbsp;</div></div>
                                                                                <!--noindex--><div style="height: 45px; text-align:center !important;">
    <a id="notinComparison29235" href="#" rel="nofollow" onclick="comparisonAdd(29235); return false;">⚖ Порівняти</a>
    <span id="inComparison29235" style="display:none;">В порівнянні <a href="/uk/compare/" rel="nofollow">Список порівняння</a></span>
</div><!--/noindex-->                               </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
```

```
for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".category_product"):
                name = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.prdbrief_name', 'Null')
                price = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.card-price', '-')
                try:
                    nal = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.card__buttons')
                    nal = 'Есть в наличии'
                except:
                    nal = 'Нет в наличии'
```

Comment: Посмотрите <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17361742/download-image-with-selenium-python>

Comment: Это не совсем то, потому что мне нужна не сама фотография, а значение в ней, при том этот парсер должен будет отрабатывать каждый день, а загружать ежедневно по 800+ картинок не хватит никаких ресурсов компа

Comment: Если картинки загружать не хотите и распознавать в них цифры, то можно воспользоваться сервисами <https://101poisk.ru/collection/servisyi-raspoznavaniya-kapchi>, правда платными.